# Entity Framework equivalent to READPAST

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, nonblocking

We have a table that is refreshed every ~15minutes via a DB job to keep the front-end updated with the latest changes from various sources.

To read this table in the past, a stored proc was called with the table hint READPAST. The intent I believe was to ensure that the table could be freely updated on its schedule, but you were also only ever given clean data for public consumption.

In LINQ with EF6, is there a way I can do this using either TransactionScope or some other mechanic? I'm aware table hints aren't explicitly supported out-of-the-box so I'm looking for alternatives. We'd like to use LINQ more and stored procs. less (especially when all they are doing is SELECTing).

Comment: Its not really LINQ feature, but a Entity Framework feature you are asking about. You should update your title to something more appropriate like "READPAST in Entity Framework" because LINQ covers a lot more than just EF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction isolation levels.  Read uncommitted will allow you to read data that is not yet committed to the table, but there may be a different isolation level that's suitable to you.  Either way, here's a post that explains it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/04/01/tips-to-avoid-deadlocks-in-entity-framework-applications.aspx